# Passing String Segue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I need to pass this string value to another viewController. For some reason I am getting a sigabrt error. Can anyone point out what im doing wrong?

**Need to pass userIdentityString value to userCellTapped viewcontroller**

```
    class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {


//Get Data of current cell that has been tapped
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

            //Eliminate highlight after cell is tapped
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

            let userIdentityString : String = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].cellUserId

            let destinationUID = userCellTapped()

            destinationUID.programVar = userIdentityString

            destinationUID.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileTapped", sender: self)


        }

}


    import UIKit

    class userCellTapped: UIViewController {

        var programVar : String!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            print("testbles", programVar)


        }


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to properly set destination view controller variables is by implementing `prepare(for segue ...)` in your `ViewController` class:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profileTapped" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MyDestinationViewControllerType {
            destination.myVariable = myClassLevelVariable
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call method

```
destinationUID.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileTapped", sender: userIdentityString)
```

you have to add Segue with identifier `"profileTapped"` into the storyboard. **Sender** in the method is the value you want to pass. As **identifier** you should pass id of that Segue.

And if you want to pass some data to that controller. Yoy have to implement additional method

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profileTapped", let vc = segue.destination as? UserCellTapped, let variable = sender as? String {
        vc.programVar = variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ;) you are much apreciated.